# How to connect QEMU directly to the outside network using command line?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, qemu

My host has 1 Ethernet controller with the IP address 192.168.1.2/24, and I want the virtual machine to be on the same subnet with the address 192.168.1.3/24.

Basically it is making a bridge interface on the host with the old IP address, and a tap interface as a member of that bridge, and use that tap interface as the backend of the virtual machine network interface. All tutorial I found always instruct me to use `libvirt` or `virt-manager`. I don't want any layer of abstration, and want to manually create the bridge on the host and use pure `qemu-system-x86_64` syntax.

How can I do it? Command line syntax is fine, but I am also interested in `netplan` syntax because it is persistent between Ubuntu reboots. I can create the bridge using `netplan` configuration file already, but do not know how to add a tap device to it.